# Route to subdomain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, subdomain

I have made an asp.net mvc 3 application with an area called blog. I want to route this area to my subdomain blog.mywebsite.com. How can I achieve this?

How do I need to define my route?
Do I have to configure the DNS?

Currently I just use the default area route.
I can access my blog area for now at this way.
mywebsite.com/blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will require a CNAME entry setting up that will redirect to your website.  Your hosting provider will be able to help out here if you are not familiar with this.

Comment: Ok. But I still need a route so asp.net mvc routes blog.mywebsite.com to my blog area. Is there someone who knows how to define this route

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Because I have 2 cnames setup and I want certain pages to go to 1 subdomain, and others to another. I am using `Html.ActionLink()`